# How can I change the code to have balanced circle positions with HTML, CSS like in the picture?

Tags: html, css

how can I adjust the code so that the circles are centred with the text blocks in all responsive break points. The text blocks aslo need to be an equal width and have centre aligned columns. The vertical spacing between text columns also needs to be equal.

I attached the picture here as well, which I want to build like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. And finish the tour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is a great fit for this layout.

> The Flexible Box Module, usually referred to as flexbox, was designed
>   as a one-dimensional layout model, and as a method that could offer
>   **space distribution between items** in an interface and powerful
>   alignment capabilities.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  margin: 12px auto;
}

.circle-txt {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3 class="circle">Circle 1</h3>
    <div class="circle-txt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Morbi scelerisque est non ipsum eleifend eleifend. 
      Duis eu sapien ac magna aliquet lacinia non ut est. 
      Quisque velit ligula, molestie vel consectetur sit amet, 
      sodales rutrum neque. 
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="circle">Circle 2</h3>
    <div class="circle-txt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Morbi scelerisque est non ipsum eleifend eleifend. 
      Duis eu sapien ac magna aliquet lacinia non ut est. 
      Quisque velit ligula, molestie vel consectetur sit amet, 
      sodales rutrum neque. 
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="circle">Circle 3</h3>
    <div class="circle-txt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Morbi scelerisque est non ipsum eleifend eleifend. 
      Duis eu sapien ac magna aliquet lacinia non ut est. 
      Quisque velit ligula, molestie vel consectetur sit amet, 
      sodales rutrum neque. 
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple procedure... You need to set width, height, border-radius properties to achieve a proper circle..

`<div style="width:100px; height:100px;border: 1px solid;border-radius: 50%; background-color: #ddd;"></div>`